# How to wait for a physic simulation result when Evaluating a chromosome with GeneticSharp in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, genetic-algorithm, geneticsharp

I am working on a racing game and currently developing an AI race system. For the AI to move in a racing track, it is directed through splines, where each point has an assigned speed limit that the AI car has to regulate to. However, setting up these speed limits on each point is a tedious process, as it varies depending on the characteristics of the vehicle.

So, I want to develop an algorithm to automate this task using Unity.

I have transposed my problem from the TSP Genetic Sharp example.
Here is my SplineChromosome class:

```
public class SplineChromosome : ChromosomeBase
{
    private readonly int _pointCount;
    public float LapTime { get; internal set; }
    
    public SplineChromosome(int pointCount) : base(pointCount)
    {
        _pointCount = pointCount;
        
        var pointsIndexes = RandomizationProvider.Current.GetUniqueInts(pointCount, 0, pointCount);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++)
        {
            ReplaceGene(i, new Gene(pointsIndexes[i]));
        }
    }
    
    public override Gene GenerateGene(int geneIndex)
    {
        return new Gene(RandomizationProvider.Current.GetInt(0, _pointCount));
    }
    
    public override IChromosome CreateNew()
    {
        return new SplineChromosome(_pointCount);
    }
    
    public override IChromosome Clone()
    {
        var clone = base.Clone() as SplineChromosome;
        clone.LapTime = LapTime;

        return clone;
    }
}
```

My GeneticAlgorithmController :

```
public class GAController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SplineCar Car;
    public int CarCount;
    public AIPath AIPath;
    public float BaseTime;

    private GeneticAlgorithm _geneticAlgorithm;
    private Thread _geneticAlgorithmThread;

    private void Start()
    {
        var fitness = new SplineFitness(AIPath, Car, BaseTime);
        var chromosome = new SplineChromosome(AIPath.Waypoints.Count);
        
        var crossover = new OrderedCrossover();
        var mutation = new ReverseSequenceMutation();
        var selection = new RouletteWheelSelection();
        var population = new Population(50, 100, chromosome);
        
        _geneticAlgorithm = new GeneticAlgorithm(population, fitness, selection, crossover, mutation)
        {
            Termination = new TimeEvolvingTermination(System.TimeSpan.FromHours(1)),
            
            // The fitness evaluation of whole population will be running on parallel.
            TaskExecutor = new ParallelTaskExecutor
            {
                MinThreads = 100,
                MaxThreads = 200
            }
        };

        // Every time a generation ends, we log the best solution.
        _geneticAlgorithm.GenerationRan += delegate
        {
            var lapTime = ((SplineChromosome)_geneticAlgorithm.BestChromosome).LapTime;
            Debug.Log($"Generation: {_geneticAlgorithm.GenerationsNumber} - LapTime: ${lapTime}");
        };
        
        // Starts the genetic algorithm in a separate thread.
        _geneticAlgorithmThread = new Thread(() => _geneticAlgorithm.Start());
        _geneticAlgorithmThread.Start();
    }
    
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // When the script is destroyed we stop the genetic algorithm and abort its thread too.
        _geneticAlgorithm.Stop();
        _geneticAlgorithmThread.Abort();
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to wait for my simulation to complete for obtaining the lap time with the values on the given chromosome. Here is my Evaluate function in the SplineFitness where I stuck:

```
public class SplineFitness : IFitness
{
    public SplineCar Car;
    public AIPath AIPath;
    public float BaseTime;

    public SplineFitness(AIPath path, SplineCar car, float baseTime)
    {
        AIPath = path;
        Car = car;
        BaseTime = baseTime;
    }
    
    public double Evaluate(IChromosome chromosome)
    {
        // Get the points speed from the chromosome
        var genes = chromosome.GetGenes();
        var lapTime = 0;

        // Applying speeds on the path
        List<AIPath.WaypointData> convertList = new List<AIPath.WaypointData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < genes.Length; i++)
        {
            var pathWaypoint = AIPath.Waypoints[i];
            float waypointSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(genes[i].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            
            convertList.Add(new AIPath.WaypointData(pathWaypoint.Point, pathWaypoint.OvertakeZoneLeft, pathWaypoint.OvertakeZoneRight, waypointSpeed));
        }
        AIPath.Waypoints = convertList;

        // Running the simulation
        lapTime = RunSimulation(); // Find a way to complete the lap with the given speed AND THEN set the time result here
        
        // Applying lap time on chromosomes
        ((SplineChromosome)chromosome).LapTime = lapTime;

        // We compare the lap time with the standard time to see if there is an improvement.
        var diffWithBase = BaseTime - lapTime;

        if (diffWithBase < 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        
        return diffWithBase;
    }

    private int RunSimulation()
    {
        // ???
        // Someting like await Car.RunLap; would be perfect ^^
        return 0;
    }
}
```

As I cannot use async-await with the Evaluate method, I can't wait for my car to complete a lap and obtain the lap time. Does anyone have an idea on how can I solve this issue?

Thanks !